# show/hide link in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have 4 links which place under seperate `<td>`, I want to show/hide the td based on a particular selection of parent object

```
<td nowrap align=right id="dis_mirr" style="visiblility: visible;">
    <a id="first" style=font-weight:normal href=javascript:createwin();>
        &nbsp;Mirror&nbsp;
    </a>
</td>
<td nowrap align=right>
    <a id="second" style=font-weight:normal href=javascript:breakwin();>
        &nbsp;Break Mirror
    </a>
</td>
```

here is code:

```
if(record.get('model') == 'top'){
    document.getElementById('first').visibility = "hidden";
}else{
    document.getElementById('first').visibility = "visible";
}
```

The code works but the `<td>` is still there it should be removed when I hide it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone for the difference between `display` and `visibility`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("first").parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: but <td> is still there. only the link is getting hide

Comment: if(record.get('model') == 'top'){
   document.getElementById('first').parentNode.style.display = "none";
  }else{
   document.getElementById('first').parentNode.style.display = "block";

  }

Comment: What do you mean by removed? Not visible to user (content and space) or actually removed from the DOM? If you want to remove the TD from DOM try this: `document.getElementById("first").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("first"));`

Comment: the content and space should not visible to user, i want to remove it from DOM. I tried your code still showing space

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your code. Check this fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/u2aYJ/1/

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the parentNode attribute, which will return the parent element, here the `<td>` :

```
if(record.get('model') == 'top'){
    document.getElementById('first').parentNode.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
    document.getElementById('first').parentNode.visibility = "visible";
}
```